# Memory alignment of an array at an index

Tags: c++, vector, simd, memory-alignment

Is it possible to tell the compiler that `vector[index]` has 128bit memory alignment for a particular index?

Or, we can't do that with index, and must do that with pointer?

Comment: I think the compiler would know that itself by looking at the type of data stored by the array

Comment: Support for alignment greater than the fundamental alignment (i.e. `alignof(std::max_align_t)` will always be up to the implementation. That said, C++17 adds better support for extended alignment, so as long as you make your *type* aligned, the elements will be so, too. On the other hand, if your types are smaller and you just want *some* elements to be aligned, then a) you should redesign your code to take advantage of the type system, and b) you'll probably need to write some manual code.

Comment: @Nana Osaberima: do you mean to just use a vector of 128bit elements? Then, as long as we can "tell" the compiler that the 0th element is aligned, the compiler will know that every element is aligned? hmm. how to do that?

Comment: In the line of what @KerrekSB said in b), you could write your own type, overload brackets operator and do the conditional alignment shift for index *index*.

Comment: @Pedro Boechat: Even when an index refers to an aligned memory address, the compiler might not know that...

Comment: Sorry, but I think I don't really understand what you want. Arrays are aligned to the size of their items. If you want your arrays items to be aligned, you could use C++11 [alignas specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) or compiler's specific directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rare I can answer a c question... But mixed language helps.

I think (s)he is asking if there is something like the icc/

```
#pragma assume aligned : 64 ::A
```

, or something like that... In ifort it is

```
!DIR$ ASSUME_ALIGNED :64 :: A
```

There are also compiler switches for array alignment, and All of it is to aid in memory transfer. Ifind it is a good practice to have.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522571

Thee is also a bunch of this stuff on the Intel webinar for Xeon-Phi and AXV-512, so I assume that there is a gcc equivalent. Just skip the 128 and go to 512 (64 bytes) and then you are AVX 512 ready ;)

The fact that one can go to 256 seems to indicate hope for AVX 2K

Comment: I like to use the analogy of moving the Mrs shoes from one side of the closet to the other side.
If lefthand (or left foot) shoeA is in box1 and right ShoeA is box2 with the left hand shoeB, then I need to essentially get the shoes back into boxes which contain the Left and right of each shoe when I end up moving them across the closet. It is much easier if I get them aligned with the boxes during compilation and execution/setup. If one only has a few shoes one should not worry as much as if it is a Ms Marcos sized collection. For large SIMD this makes some difference.